# Sending with PHPMailer works with one address but not another

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have been using an email address to send using PHPMailer, I'm getting user information successfully, but when I use another email address it fails to send.
Also I have tried to changes port number 25/2525 instead of 587.

This is an HTML5 & Javascript registration form sending user details to contact.mailer.php.

```
$fileNameSubmitterName=str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
$target_path = "/var/www/html/cdl/uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path .$fileNameSubmitterName.'_'.basename( $_FILES['test_upload_image']['name']); 
print_r(" target path "+ $target_path);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_upload_image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  // echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['test_upload_image']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else {
   //echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

$to = "aa@gmail.com";

$from=$email;
$from_name= "india";
$subject = "Feedback from india.org website";
//$body="Test Body-";

$message = " Name: " . $name . "\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Phone: " . $phone . "\r\n address: " . $address . "\r\n Qualification: " . $qualification . "\r\n number:" . $number . "\r\n date:" . $date . "\r\n bank:" . $bank . "\r\n Feedback: " . $feedback;
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object

$error='';
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
//print_r("sta2");

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->Username = "india@gmail.com";  
//$mail->Username = "vaag@gmail.com";  
//print_r("sta2");
//$mail->Password = "pr"; 
$mail->Password = "br"; 
$mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->addAttachment($target_path); 
//print_r("stage1");

if(!$mail->Send()) {        
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message not sent. Please try again!.");</script>';

    print "<script>document.location.href='institute.org';</script>";
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message sent succesfully. We will conact you soon.");</script>';
    print "<script>document.location.href=institute.org';</script>";
}

//print_r($error);
}

?>
```

I have to send same input fields to other Email address it's not sending.

Comment: Is it just a a typo: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';`? It should be `tls`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer, and you have based your code on an obsolete example. I'd recommend you start again using [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

You do have a simple typo:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
```

should be

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Your code doesn't show where `$email` comes from, but from what you're putting into the message body, I'm assuming that it's provided in a form field by the user, and then your'e doing this:

```
$from=$email;
$mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
```

This is forgery, and will not work with gmail. Do this instead:

```
$mail->setFrom('india@gmail.com', $from_name);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);
$mail->addAddress($to);
```

This way you will not be forging the from address, but replies will go to the submitter's address. Note that even when you set the from name, your email client may ignore it in favour of a previous name that you've seen from the same address - this is not something you can control.

You can set the port number to 25 or 2525 simply with `$mail->Port = 25;`, however, since you're sending through gmail, you should stick with 587 as that's the right port to use for SMTP submissions using STARTTLS for encryption (which you selected by setting `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`; an alternative is to use `'ssl'` mode on port 465).

Overall, you're not doing any error checking at all, so your script will allow invalid email addresses. The PHPMailer contact form example shows the right way to handle this.

Comment: $mail->setFrom('india@gmail.com', $from_name);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);
$mail->addAddress($to);

Comment: Mr.Synchro thank you very much, spending your valuable time.I have tried PHP mailer, this code which one you suggested me yesterday.But its showing like page is not working.I am just trying to solve issue but can't. I have updated code same thing. $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                                                                             $mail->setFrom('india@gmail.com', $from_name);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);
$mail->addAddress($to);

Comment: I can’t help without complete code or error messages. Check your logs.

Comment: Thank you.I will update complete code details.Please where is I'm getting error.I wanted to see.How should I can send code details.

Comment: Edit your question to show relevant code, e.g. to show where `$email` is set. General questions for how to debug PHP are too broad, and there are many resources to help you, such as in articles like [this one](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php). Main things: find and look at what's in your web server's logs, enable error display in your PHP dev environment.